# DropDown List Validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I need to perform a validation to check whether a TextBox value is empty on Dropown list selected Index change using validation controls in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work fine.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter the Value"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```